# In python, why we can create a new attribute from an instance and not a method?

Tags: python, oop

In the following code,

```
# An example class with some variable and a method 
class ExampleClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10

    def dummyPrint(self):
        print ('Hello World!')

# Creating instance and printing the init variable
inst_a = ExampleClass()
# This prints --> __init__ variable = 10
print ('__init__ variable = %d' %(inst_a.var))
# This prints --> Hello World!
inst_a.dummyPrint()

# Creating a new attribute and printing it. 
# This prints --> New variable = 20
inst_a.new_var = 20
print ('New variable = %d' %(inst_a.new_var))

# Trying to create new method, which will give error
inst_a.newDummyPrint()
```

I am able to create a new **attribute** (new_var) outside the class, using instance. And it works. Ideally, I was expecting it will not work.

Similarly I tried creating new **method** (newDummyPrint()); which will print *AttributeError: 'ExampleClass' object has no attribute 'newDummyPrint'* as I expected.

My question is,

1. Why did creating a new attribute worked?
2. Why creating a new method didn't work?

Comment: `inst_a.new_var = ...` assigns a value to a (new) attribute. `inst_a.newDummyPrint()` does ***not*** "create" a new method, it's just trying to *call* one.

Comment: You didn't actually create `inst_a.newDummyPrint` anywhere. You just jumped straight to trying to call it. You would have gotten the same error with `inst_a.new_var` if you jumped straight to trying to read it without setting a value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentionned in comments, you are creating the new attribute here:

```
inst_a.new_var = 20
```

before reading it on the next line. You're NOT assigning `newDummyPrint` anywhere, so obviously the attribute resolution mechanism cannot find it and ends up raising an AtributeError. You'd get the very same result if you tried to access any other non-existing attribute, ie `inst_a.whatever`.

Note that since in Python everything is an object (including classes, functions etc), there are no real distinction between accessing a "data" attribute or a method - they are all attributes (whether class or instance ones), and the attribute resolution rules are the same. In the case of methods (or any other callable attribute), the call operation happens *after* the attribute has been resolved.

To dynamically create a new "method", you mainly have two solutions: creating as a class attribute (which will make it available to all other instances of the class), or as an instance attribute (which will  - obviously - make it available only on this exact instance.

The first solution is as simple as it can be: define your function and bind it to the class:

```
# nb: inheriting from `object` for py2 compat

class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self, var):
         self.var = var


def bar(self, x):
    return self.var * x

# testing before:
f = Foo(42)
try:
    print(f.bar(2))
except AttribteError as e:
    print(e)

# now binds the function to the class:
Foo.bar = bar

# and test it:
print(f.bar(2))

# and it's also available on other instances:
f2 = Foo(6)
print(f2.bar(7))
```

Creating per-instance method is a (very tiny) bit more involved - you have to manually get the method from the function and bind this method to the instance:

```
def baaz(self):
    return "{}.var = {}".format(self, self.var)

# test before:
try:
    print(f.baaz())
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)


# now binds the method to the instance
f.baaz = baaz.__get__(f, Foo)

# now `f` has a `baaz` method    
print(f.baaz())

# but other Foo instances dont
try:
    print(f2.baaz())
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
```

You'll noticed I talked about functions in the first case and methods in the second case. [A python "method" is actually just a thin callable wrapper around a function, an instance and a class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod), and is provided by the `function` type through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) - which is automagically invoked when the attribute is resolved on the class itself (=> is a class attribute implementin the descriptor protocol) but not when resolved on the instance. This why, in the second case, we have to manually invoke the descriptor protocol.

Also note that there are limitations on what's possible here: first, [`__magic__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) (all methods named with two leading and two trailing underscores) are only looked up on the class itself so you cannot define them on a per-instance basis. Then, [slots-based](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) types and some builtin or C-coded types do not support dynamic attributes whatsoever. Those restrictions are mainly there for performance optimization reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Bruno. Your first method made me to understand my mistake! 
Note: I am a beginner in OOP with Python. While practicing I got this doubt. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new attributes on the fly when you are using an empty class definition [emulating Pascal "record" or C "struct"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends). Otherwise, what you are trying to do is not a *good manner*, or a good *pattern* for object-oriented programming. There are lots of books you can read about it. Generally speaking, you have to clearly tell in the class definition what an object of that class is, how it behaves: modifying its behavior on the fly (e.g. adding new methods) could lead to unknown results, which make your life impossible when reading that code a month later and even worse when you are debugging.
There is even an anti-pattern problem called *Ambiguous Viewpoint*:

> Lack of clarification of the modeling viewpoint leads to problematic
>   ambiguities in object models.

Anyway, if you are playing with Python and **you swear you'll never use this code in production**, you can write new attributes which store lambda functions, e.g.

```
c = ExampleClass()
c.newMethod = lambda s1, s2: str(s1) + ' and ' + str(s2)
print(c.newMethod('string1', 'string2'))
# output is: string1 and string2
```

but this is very ugly, I would **never** do it.

Comment: You can (technically) add new attributes and methods regardless of whether the class definition is empty or not - FWIW you can even dynamically change the class of an object if you want (but it's usually not a good idea). wrt/ good practices, it's indeed better to avoid _abusing_ Python's dynamic nature, but you "should" certainly not refrain from wisely _using_ it where it makes sense - and it does make sense in quite a few cases. As an example, Django's ORM uses this feature to create reverse relation descriptors for models foreign keys.

Comment: Also note that in your above example, you're not adding a _method_ to the instance, you're adding a plain function (a method can access the instance) - and what's __really__ ugly in this example is using a lambda instead of a clear function definition.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I totally agree with you

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for your reply. I am very new to OOPs in Python. While practicing I am getting such doubts (I have taken a MOOC). Thank you both for clarifying!

Comment: @AravindD.Chakravarti Note that Python's object model is a bit peculiar when compared to mainstream static languages like C++ / Java / C# - but it's very powerful once you understand how it works. Also quite a lot of "learning resources" on OO (whatever the language) are totally inept (to be polite). The very best resource on OO design (once you get the basic concepts) is the first part of [the GOF's "Design pattern"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/design-patterns-elements/0201633612/), which I strongly suggest you get yourself a copy of.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the book suggestion. Will surely look into it.